# Autogenerate ID in Leads

Tags: sugarcrm

```
I have 1 custom field in Leads. I want number to restart from 1 everyday. Suppose there are 8 transactions on Day 1 no should be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8. Next day if there are 5 then number should be 1,2,3,4,5.
```

we are using SugarCrm community edition

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What do you count as a transaction? Do you mean a new case is opened?

It sounds like this would be best done from a logic hook...

Comment: Logic hooks seems the right way to go. Maybe in another module you have informations concerning the transactions? I would add the number there. Search this transaction module ordered by date_entered and retrieve only one item (limit 1). Then you increase the number found in you custom field by 1. thats it :-)

Comment: Hi , I want on the basis of no of transactions in Leads on that day . On Next day ID should restart from one. Can u provide me some example.